# ARM-friendly visual odometry node?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, visual-odometry, viso2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any good visual odometry nodes that play well with ARM? I have an Xtion Pro Live, an Odroid U3, and an itch to make them play together. viso2 requires SSE and `ccny_rgbd_tools` has yet to be converted to a wet package (not that this is a huge issue). `svo` caught my eye, but it [claims](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo/wiki/Obtaining-Best-Performance) that it's not currently well-suited to forward motion. Has anyone had any success on this front?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197314/arm-friendly-visual-odometry-node?/) by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13689 on 2014-11-12

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tanmay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18176/tanmay/) on 2015-06-02**:
Have you managed to run ccny_rgbd on the Odroid? I'm trying to do the same.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-06-03**:
I think I may have, but it didn't work out for one reason or another. I want to try rtabmap as @Bhargav suggested. It uses very little CPU on my laptop, so perhaps my ARM board will get away with it.

**Comment by [Tanmay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18176/tanmay/) on 2015-06-03**:
Thanks for the information. Do let me know if rtabmap works well for you - I'll try meddling with it then.
Also, (sorry for digressing), would you happen to know how to configure the tf tree for ccny_rgbd?

**Comment by [Tanmay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18176/tanmay/) on 2015-06-03**:
Your robot_localization packages looks pretty cool. I shall try it out once I have a map to use it on!

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-06-03**:
I'm afraid I don't recall much about `ccny_rgbd`. Also, my package name is a bit misleading - it's really for doing pose estimation through sensor fusion (no map required).

**Comment by [Tanmay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18176/tanmay/) on 2015-06-15**:
Hi Tom,
I have been trying to use rtabmap - it compiles fine on my laptop, but I am unable to compile it on my Odroid. Also, no luck finding the binary for apt-get. Have you seen otherwise?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-06-16**:
Sorry, my ARM stuff is really a side project, and I haven't had much time to devote to it. Why does it fail to build? Does it use SSE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have tried various visual odometry solutions on the [Jetson TX1](http://www.nvidia.com/object/jetson-tx1-module.html) (Quad-core ARM Cortex-A57 CPU). I have used (in no specific order):

- RTABMap - Built from source, few modifications needed. If you suggest a suitable place to detail the steps I took, I can post these.
- [ORB_SLAM2](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2) - Built from source, same as above.
- [LSD_SLAM](https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam) -  Also built from source. By default uses SSE, is kind of slow with this disabled. Same as previous two, happy to share.
- ZED Camera SDK - Closed source, but their built in tracking works wonders ... I wonder which algorithm they use under the hood, probably a modification of a leader.

All of these work on the Jetson with reasonable frame-rates and accuracy. For completeness sake here are my scrap notes for building, but as mentioned if there is an appropriate place to detail these correctly, I will.

[LSD SLAM Notes](https://rexbionics-my.sharepoint.com/personal/manu_lange_rexbionics_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=w%2fKCnJNPemkl%2fwRJX5LOPCsk1qkGMxR9Z7K2NhBRMgg%3d&docid=05b1b0d23fddb4b60a5263716db7c091f)

[ORB_SLAM2 Notes](https://rexbionics-my.sharepoint.com/personal/manu_lange_rexbionics_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=P%2f7OQX2fUbehHBiO6LPtetitmmav2FCdkRU%2b7GVZNf4%3d&docid=048bfffe3fc0c4aa8b606cd23ff64d3bb)

[RTABMap Notes](https://rexbionics-my.sharepoint.com/personal/manu_lange_rexbionics_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=CMdxUrZqsnnqjhatlcv6jb3vcoJB5121XeiR5Ju%2fBPg%3d&docid=08d519a9d3af249fa92f736ad62d98539)

---

Originally posted by [NZNobody](https://answers.ros.org/users/27466/nznobody/) with karma: 156 on 2016-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4